# Why can't SciPy's curve_fit find the covariance/give me sensical parameters for this higher order gaussian function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

Here's some minimal code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
xdata = [16.530468600170202, 16.86156794563677, 17.19266729110334, 17.523766636569913,
 17.854865982036483, 18.18596532750305, 18.51706467296962, 18.848164018436194, 19.179263363902763,
 19.510362709369332]
ydata = [394, 1121, 1173, 1196, 1140, 1196, 1158, 1160, 1046, 416]
#function i'm trying to fit the data to (higher order gaussian function)
def gauss(x, sig, n, c, x_o):
    return c*np.exp(-(x-x_o)**n/(2*sig**n))
popt = curve_fit(gauss, xdata, ydata)
#attempt at printing out parameters
print(popt)
```

When I try to execute the code, I get this error message:

```
ExCurveFit:9: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  return c*np.exp(-(x-x_o)**n/(2*sig**n))
C:\Users\dsneh\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:828: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',
(array([nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([[inf, inf, inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf, inf]]))
```

I've seen that I should ignore the first one, but perhaps it is a problem. The second one is more concerning, and I obviously would like more sensical values for the parameters. I've tried adding parameters as guesses ([2,3,1000,17] for reference), but it did not help.

Comment: It seems that the optimisation process can not find a suitable optimum. Have you tried using different `methods` for example `trf` and restrict the values of the parameters with `bounds`?

Comment: I haven't. The issue is that the output is complex for some values of n, so I'd like to restrict it to multiples of .4 if possible. This is possible by brute-forcing, and from a preliminary google it seems like trf can handle "sparse" problems. Does that mean I could adapt this to solve the problem without brute forcing?

Comment: You can use the `bounds` attribute to restrict `x_o` to always be smaller than your lowest data point `x`. This would prevent that your output becomes complex. However, `bounds` can not be used to restrict `n` to integers only. The question is whether your data can be explained with such an `x_o`. Without knowing your actual data, I will guess that `x_o` most certainly should not be restricted. I think your chances of success should be higher with the brute-force `n` method.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are running into this problem because `curve_fit` is also testing non-integer values of `n`, in which case your function `gauss` returns complex values when `x<x_o`.

I believe it would be easier to brute-force your way through every integer `n` and find the best parameters `sig,c,x_o` for each `n`.
For example, if you consider `n = 0,1,2,...` up to perhaps 50, there are very few options for `n`, and brute forcing is actually a decent method.
Looking at your data, it would be even better to only consider `n` as a multiple of 2 (unless your other data looks like `n` could be an odd integer).

Also, you should probably introduce some bounds for the other parameters, like it would be good to have `sig>0`, and you can safely set `c>0` (that is, if all of your data looks like the minimal data you included in your question).

Here is what I did:

```py
p0 = [1,1200,18] # initial guess for sig,c,x_o
bounds = ([0.01,100,10],[1000,2500,200]) # (lower,upper) bounds for sig,c,x_o
min_err = np.inf # error to minimize to find the best value for n

for n in range(0,41,2): # n = 0,2,4,6,...,40

    def gauss(x, sig, c, x_o, n=n):
        return c*np.exp(-(x-x_o)**n/(2*sig**n))
    
    popt,pcov = curve_fit(gauss, xdata, ydata, p0=p0, bounds=bounds)

    err = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)).sum()
    if err < min_err:
        min_err, best_n, best_popt, best_pcov = err, n, popt, pcov

print(min_error, best_n, best_popt, best_pcov, sep='\n')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(xdata,ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, gauss(xdata, *best_popt, n=best_n))
plt.show()
```

I get `best_n = 10` and `best_popt = [1.38, 1173.52, 18.02]`.

Here is the plot of the result: (the blue line is the data, and the orange line is the gauss fit)

[image: best fit]

Comment: I see, thanks! I somehow missed the fact that the output was complex sometimes.